# looking for query

Tags: database

Im trying to find  me based on city.(not using lat and long).
i have following function but as a newbie to gremlin im not sure is a right approach or not.

```
 async function addRestfgaurant(restaur) {
        // to add restaurants
```

after adding restaurant will do the same while adding Person with edlivesIn then will try to query restaurants near me. (im trying to make dining by friend api)

i want to Know is it right approach or not? or if someone has example of this type of query it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is reasonable but you can simplify things a bit. By using `as` steps to label earlier parts of the query you can then refer to them in the `from` and `to` parts. Note that in my example I also changed it to be all one query rather than three.

```
 async function addRestaurant(restaurant:InputRestaurant) {
        // to add restaurants
          await  g.addV("Restaurant").as('r').
          property("restaurantId", restaurant.restaurantId).
          property("name", restaurant.name).
          property("city", restaurant.city).
          property("street", restaurant.street).next()
         // to add city
         .addV("city").property("cityName", restaurant.city).as('c').
         //edge
         .addE("withIn")
          .from_('r')
          .to('c')).next()
          return { 
                name: restaurant.name,
                restaurantId: restaurant.restaurantId,
                city: restaurant.city,
                street: restaurant.street,
           }
```